# Sum of power series when $x$ is not center

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I have power series: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-1}{2^n}(x-1)^n$$ and I need to find sum of it. I know how to do it when it's only $(x-0)^n = x^n$, but I never did anything like this, so I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you "know how to do it when it's only $x^n$," then can't you get an expression for that, and then replace $x$ with $x-1$ in the final expression?

Comment: Write $y=x-1$ and proceed as usual.  Or just pretend that $x-1$ is $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$. Suppsose the power series converges to a function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$  for some interval $I$. Then for all $x\in I$,
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$$
which implies,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x-1)^k=f(x-1)$$
for all $x\in \{u\in\mathbb{R}:u-1\in I\}$.

Comment: So basically, it's `u = x - 1`?